# Hunting down a redirect / rewrite issue. How many rewrites should there be for a product?

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite

For SEO value I understand that Magento will redirect system ID urls to pretty urls. I'm trying to find out if there is something wrong with my db. There are several system urls that have 5 different entries. The main entry is the system url to the pretty url but there will be several others that don't seem to make sense.

How many urls should be generated for one system generated url?

System example: mywebsite.com/catalog/category/view/id/712

Pretty Url: mywebsite.com/category-parent/category-sub.html

I've got 700 products with nearly 5000 url rewrites. I thought that was a bit excessive.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. some products url are coming with .html and some with www.example.com/catalog/product/view/id/1459/s/jewelry-and-watch-storage-box-1/category/10245/   if you find any solution then Please, share here.